# Repeating a drawing and connecting them together to form one unit

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code which produces the following drawing as a part of a more complicated drawing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\node [thin, black] (0,0) (origin){}
 ([shift={(0.:1.2)}]origin.center) node (txtu){}
 ([shift={(-65.:4.)}]origin.center) node (txtd){}
 ([shift={(180.:7.)}]txtd.center) node (txtds){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.8)}]txtds.center) node (txtdt){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.4)}]origin.center) node (od){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.)}]od.center) node (odsens){}
 ([shift={(-90.:9.8)}]odsens.center) node (odsensd){}
 ([shift={(0.:.12)}]od.center) node (odr){}
 ([shift={(0.:3.)}]od.center) node (odrr){}
 ([shift={(180.:.12)}]od.center) node (odl){}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]od.center) node (odll){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.26)}]odrr.center) node (odrrd){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.12)}]odll.center) node (odllc){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.24)}]odll.center) node (odlld){}
;
 \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] (odr.center) -- ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odr.center) .. controls (40:1.2) and (140:1.2) .. ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odl.center) -- (odl.center);
 \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] ([shift={(180.:.02)}]odr.center) -- (odrr.center) -- (odrrd.center) -- (odlld.center) -- (odll.center) --  ([shift={(0.:.02)}]odl.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to repeat this drawing 2 times downwards and connect them together to form one unit, to look like the following drawing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it to define a macro, `\MyComponents` to do the drawing of the components and then draw the line connecting them.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyComponents}[2][]{%
    %% #1 = drawing options
    %% #2 = name of node
    \begin{scope}[scale=.5, transform shape, #1]
        \node [thin, black] (0,0) (origin) {}
         ([shift={(0.:1.2)}]origin.center) node (txtu){}
         ([shift={(-65.:4.)}]origin.center) node (txtd){}
         ([shift={(180.:7.)}]txtd.center) node (txtds){}
         ([shift={(180.:5.8)}]txtds.center) node (txtdt){}
         ([shift={(-90.:.4)}]origin.center) node (od){}
         ([shift={(180.:5.)}]od.center) node (odsens){}
         ([shift={(-90.:9.8)}]odsens.center) node (odsensd){}
         ([shift={(0.:.12)}]od.center) node (odr){}
         ([shift={(0.:3.)}]od.center) node (odrr){}
         ([shift={(180.:.12)}]od.center) node (odl){}
         ([shift={(180.:1.)}]od.center) node (odll){}
         ([shift={(-90.:.26)}]odrr.center) node (odrrd){}
         ([shift={(-90.:.12)}]odll.center) node (odllc){}
         ([shift={(-90.:.24)}]odll.center) node (odlld){}
        ;
         \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] (odr.center) -- ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odr.center) .. controls (40:1.2) and (140:1.2) .. ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odl.center) -- (odl.center);
         \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] ([shift={(180.:.02)}]odr.center) -- (odrr.center) -- (odrrd.center) -- (odlld.center) -- (odll.center) --  ([shift={(0.:.02)}]odl.center);
         
         \coordinate (#2 Top) at (odll.center);
         \coordinate (#2 Bot) at (odlld.center);
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \MyComponents{Node 1}
    \MyComponents[yshift=-1.5cm]{Node 2}
    \MyComponents[yshift=-3.0cm]{Node 3}
    
    \draw [blue, line width=3pt] ([yshift=0.5pt]Node 1 Top) -- ([yshift=-0.5pt]Node 3 Bot);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to connect the drawings with a filled rectangle, not a line. So, to do this later, I added some nodes, and I tried the solution I posted in the following question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456100/repeating-a-drawing-and-connecting-them-together-to-form-one-unit-trial); but I got an error of elongated rounded objects, that I could not solve. Can you help me.