# Repeating a drawing and connecting them together to form one unit trial

Tags: tikz-pgf

in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456071/repeating-a-drawing-and-connecting-them-together-to-form-one-unit), I tried the following solution

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\node [thin, black] (0,0) (origin){}
 ([shift={(0.:1.2)}]origin.center) node (txtu){}
 ([shift={(-65.:4.)}]origin.center) node (txtd){}
 ([shift={(180.:7.)}]txtd.center) node (txtds){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.8)}]txtds.center) node (txtdt){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.4)}]origin.center) node (od){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.)}]od.center) node (odsens){}
 ([shift={(-90.:9.8)}]odsens.center) node (odsensd){}
 ([shift={(0.:.12)}]od.center) node (odr){}
 ([shift={(0.:3.)}]od.center) node (odrr){}
 ([shift={(180.:.12)}]od.center) node (odl){}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]od.center) node (odll){}
 ([shift={(180.:.2)}]odll.center) node (odlll){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.26)}]odrr.center) node (odrrd){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.12)}]odll.center) node (odllc){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.24)}]odll.center) node (odlld){}
 ([shift={(-90.:1.)}]origin.center) node (originb){}
 ([shift={(0.:1.2)}]originb.center) node (txtub){}
 ([shift={(-65.:4.)}]originb.center) node (txtdb){}
 ([shift={(180.:7.)}]txtdb.center) node (txtdsb){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.8)}]txtdsb.center) node (txtdtb){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.4)}]originb.center) node (odb){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.)}]odb.center) node (odsensb){}
 ([shift={(-90.:9.8)}]odsensb.center) node (odsensdb){}
 ([shift={(0.:.12)}]odb.center) node (odrb){}
 ([shift={(0.:3.)}]odb.center) node (odrrb){}
 ([shift={(180.:.12)}]odb.center) node (odlb){}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]odb.center) node (odllb){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.26)}]odrrb.center) node (odrrdb){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.12)}]odllb.center) node (odllcb){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.24)}]odllb.center) node (odlldb){}
 ([shift={(-90.:2.)}]origin.center) node (originc){}
 ([shift={(0.:1.2)}]originc.center) node (txtuc){}
 ([shift={(-65.:4.)}]originc.center) node (txtdc){}
 ([shift={(180.:7.)}]txtdc.center) node (txtdsc){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.8)}]txtdsc.center) node (txtdtc){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.4)}]originc.center) node (odc){}
 ([shift={(180.:5.)}]odc.center) node (odsensc){}
 ([shift={(-90.:9.8)}]odsensc.center) node (odsensdc){}
 ([shift={(0.:.12)}]odc.center) node (odrc){}
 ([shift={(0.:3.)}]odc.center) node (odrrc){}
 ([shift={(180.:.12)}]odc.center) node (odlc){}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]odc.center) node (odllc){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.26)}]odrrc.center) node (odrrdc){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.12)}]odllc.center) node (odllcc){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.24)}]odllc.center) node (odlldc){}
 ([shift={(180.:.2)}]odlldc.center) node (odlldlc){}
;
 \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] (odr.center) -- ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odr.center) .. controls (40:1.2) and (140:1.2) .. ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odl.center) -- (odl.center)

 (odrb.center) -- ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odrb.center) .. controls (40:1.2) and (140:1.2) .. ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odlb.center) -- (odlb.center)

 (odrc.center) -- ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odrc.center) .. controls (40:1.2) and (140:1.2) .. ([shift={(90.:.4)}]odlc.center) -- (odlc.center)
;

 \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] ([shift={(180.:.02)}]odr.center) -- (odrr.center) -- (odrrd.center) -- (odlld.center) -- (odll.center) -- ([shift={(0.:.02)}]odl.center);

 \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] ([shift={(180.:.02)}]odrb.center) -- (odrrb.center) -- (odrrdb.center) -- (odlldb.center) -- (odllb.center) -- ([shift={(0.:.02)}]odlb.center);

 \draw[thick, purple!60!black, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!60, opacity=.4] ([shift={(180.:.02)}]odrc.center) -- (odrrc.center) -- (odrrdc.center) -- (odlldc.center) -- (odllc.center) -- ([shift={(0.:.02)}]odlc.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

which gave me the following drawing

[image]

How can I avoid the elongated rounded shapes  to make it look like this

[image]

Later on I would like to connect them to look like this drawing

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the same exact control points for all three shapes. That is, when you do

```
.. controls (40:1.2) and (140:1.2) ..
```

`(40:1.2)` and `(140:2)` are in the same position, they're not relative to the previous point on the path. To solve this, use relative coordinates as in

```
.. controls +(40:1.2) and +(140:1.2) ..
```

FYI, if I remember correctly, when you do

```
(a_x, a_y) .. controls +(x1,y1) and +(x2,y2) .. (b_x, b_y)
```

the two control points will be placed at `(a_x+x1, a_y+y1)` and `(b_x+x2, b_y+y2)`, respectively.

#### Addendum

Depending on your needs, a different approach to drawing those shapes might be easier to handle. You could for example use a `pic` like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  myshape/.pic={
     \draw[thick,
           purple!60!black,
           top color=red,
           bottom color=red,
           middle color=red!60,
           opacity=.4]
        (0,0) coordinate (-ll) |- (0.6,0.2) -- (0.6,0.3)
        .. controls +(140:0.6) and +(40:0.6) .. coordinate [midway] (-top)
        (0.8,0.3) |- (2.2,0.2) coordinate (-ur) |- (0,0);
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {0,1,2}
   \pic (s-\y) at (0,0.65*\y) {myshape};

\draw (s-0-top) to[bend right] (s-2-ur);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This particular version doesn't exactly reproduce your diagram, but it's much easier to change, as you only need to change the definition of the `pic` and all three instances of it change.

Comment: It's also possible to add named coordinates to the `pic`, which can be referenced.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation. Can you please tell me how to add named coordinates to the pic, to reference them. I want to connect the ends of the drawings to make them look like the drawing I added to my question.

Comment: @Hany Basically if you have `coordinate (foo)` inside the `pic` definition, and you give the `pic` a name with `\pic (bar) {myshape}`, then you can refer to the coordinate inside the `pic` with `barfoo`. So name of pic followed by name of coordinate inside pic. I updated the code with an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I will name the coordinates I want to draw from-to as in your example.